# loop through and conditional check

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs, html to show table and display the records in the table. I want to iterate the column value and strike through the value in the column if the condition satisfies.

Demo:http://plnkr.co/edit/EtikF47DBvJ6bOIB8JSm?p=preview&preview

I want to strike through the associate number in the table(AssociateNum column) for which the result(column) is Delivered..
Example.,For associate number 21,10,133 the result are Delivered,shipped,shipped.
I want to strike through the associate number 21 for which the result is Delivered(similarly for all rows in the table).

html:

```
 <table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players">
    <td ng-cloak data-ng-class="player.standing && 'null' || 'strikethrough'">{{ player.name }}</td>
    <td>
    <a ng-repeat="associateNum in player.associatedNumber .split(',')" href="https://urladdr/associateid={{associateNum}}" target="_blank">
                            {{associateNum}}<span ng-if="$index+1 != player.associatedNumber.split(',').length">;</span></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ player.standing }}
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

js code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.players = [{
    "name": "Robert C",
    "associatedNumber": "21,10,133",
    "standing": true,
    "result":"Delivered,shipped,shipped"
}, {
    "name": "Joey C",
    "associatedNumber": "55,2",
    "standing": false,
    "result":"To be delivered,Delivered"
}, {
    "name": "Bobby A",
    "associatedNumber": "15",
    "standing": true,
    "result":"TO be delivered"
}, {
    "name": "John A",
    "associatedNumber": "1,33,34",
    "standing": true,
    "result":"To be delivered,shipped"
}];
});
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: @nan did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

I've put the `associateNum` in it's own span-element which get's a class assigned, when the corresponding `result` is equal to "Delivered"

```
<span data-ng-class="player.result.split(',')[$index] === 'Delivered' ? 'strikethrough' : 'null'">{{associateNum}}</span>
```

You'd probably want to remove the strikethrough class adding for the names though ;)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.players = [{
    "name": "Robert C",
    "associatedNumber": "21,10,133",
    "standing": true,
    "result":"Delivered,shipped,shipped"
}, {
    "name": "Joey C",
    "associatedNumber": "55,2",
    "standing": false,
    "result":"To be delivered,Delivered"
}, {
    "name": "Bobby A",
    "associatedNumber": "15",
    "standing": true,
    "result":"TO be delivered"
}, {
    "name": "John A",
    "associatedNumber": "1,33,34",
    "standing": true,
    "result":"To be delivered,shipped"
}];
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players">
    <td ng-cloak data-ng-class="player.standing && 'null' || 'strikethrough'">{{ player.name }}</td>
    <td>
    <a ng-repeat="associateNum in player.associatedNumber .split(',')" href="https://urladdr/associateid={{associateNum}}" target="_blank">
      <span data-ng-class="player.result.split(',')[$index] === 'Delivered' ? 'strikethrough' : 'null'">{{associateNum}}</span><span ng-if="$index+1 != player.associatedNumber.split(',').length">;</span>
    </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ player.standing }}
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `ng-class` in conjunction with the conditional statement and requisite CSS:

```
ng-class="{strike: player.result.indexOf('Delivered') > -1}"
```

Example:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players">
        <td ng-cloak data-ng-class="player.standing && 'null' || 'strikethrough'">{{ player.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <a 
                ng-class="{strike: player.result.indexOf('Delivered') > -1}"
                ng-repeat="associateNum in player.associatedNumber.split(',')" href="https://urladdr/associateid={{associateNum}}" target="_blank">
                {{ associateNum }}
                <span ng-if="$index + 1 != player.associatedNumber.split(',').length">;</span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ player.standing }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.strike { text-decoration: line-through; }
```